UnhandledSchemeError with node:crypto when using @node-rs/argon2 in Next.js 14.2.6
I'm working on a Next.js project (version 14.2.6) and encountering an issue related to the @node-rs/argon2 package. The build process fails with an UnhandledSchemeError for the node:crypto module. The error details are as follows:
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:crypto" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
Import trace for requested module:
node:crypto
./node_modules/argon2/argon2.cjs
./auth.ts

Here’s what I’m seeing in the terminal when I run npm run dev:
⨯ node:crypto
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:crypto" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Import trace for requested module:
node:crypto
./node_modules/argon2/argon2.cjs
./auth.ts

...
⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
GET / 500 in 48ms
GET /users 404 in 2ms
Additional Context:
Next.js Version: 14.2.6
NextAuth.js Version: 5
Argon2 Package: argon2
Node.js Version: 18.x.x
Operating System: Kali Linux
Environment Variables: Loaded via .env
Custom Webpack Configuration: None (using the default provided by Next.js)

Question:
How can I configure Webpack or Next.js to properly handle the node:crypto module when using the argon2 package? Is there a specific plugin or workaround required to address this UnhandledSchemeError?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve Tried:
I’ve verified that the issue is related to the node:crypto module, which is used internally by the argon2 package.
I've tried to search for a plugin or configuration that would allow Webpack to handle node: URIs but haven't been able to find a solution.
The issue persists with Fast Refresh triggering full reloads and runtime errors, leading to 500 and 404 responses during development.

This works for me (next v14.2.7)
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["@node-rs/argon2"],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

